# Array with object; splitting text line into object members?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I need some help with this code. The problem is I dont know how to split a loaded line into the object members and then push it `toString()` method and then out into another file. Heres's the main code:

```
public class TXTtoJSON {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String fileName = "temp.csv";
        String line = null; 


    transaction trans=new transaction();

        try {

        FileReader fileReader=new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader= new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("json.json");
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

            while((line=bufferedReader.readLine()) !=null) {


                bufferedWriter.write(line + "\n");

                System.out.println(line);

            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            bufferedWriter.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to open File '" + fileName + "'");
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and heres the class transaction

```
public class transaction {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String routine_name;
    private String correct_count;
    private String stopless;
    private String startless;
    private String average;
    private String min;
    private String max;
    private String sum;
    private String percent;

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("{\"index\":{\"_index:\"test\",\"_id\":").append(id);
        sb.append("}}\n");
        sb.append("{\"BBL\":").append(name);
        sb.append(",\"SERVICE\":").append(routine_name);
        sb.append(",\"Correct Count\":").append(correct_count);
        sb.append(",\"Stopless\":").append(stopless);
        sb.append(",\"Startless\":").append(startless);
        sb.append(",\"Average\":").append(average);
        sb.append(",\"Min\":").append(min);
        sb.append(",\"Max\":").append(max);
        sb.append(",\"Sum\":").append(sum);
        sb.append(",\"Percent\":").append(percent);
        sb.append("}\n");
        return sb.toString();

    }
    public String get_id() {
        return id;
    }
    public void set_id(String id) {
        this.id=id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }
    public String GetRoutineName() {
        return routine_name;
    }
    public void SetRoutineName(String routine_name) {
        this.routine_name=routine_name;
    }
    public String get_count() {
        return correct_count;
    }
    public void set_count(String count) {
        this.correct_count=count;
    }
    public String getStopless() {
        return stopless;
    }
    public void setStopless(String stop) {
        this.stopless=stop;
    }
    public String getStartless() {
        return startless;
    }
    public void setStartless(String start) {
        this.startless=start;
    }
    public String getAverage() {
        return average;
    }
    public void setAverage(String average) {
        this.average=average;
    }
    public String getMin() {
        return startless;
    }
    public void setMin(String min) {
        this.min=min;
    }
    public String getMax() {
        return max;
    }
    public void setMax(String max) {
        this.max=max;
    }
    public String getSum() {
        return sum;
    }
    public void setSum(String sum) {
        this.sum=sum;
    }
    public String getPercent() {
        return percent;
    }
    public void setPercent(String percent) {
        this.percent=percent;
    }
}
```

I hope u see the problem, I know how to write into a file, but i cant get it to the format i want with the toString method? Also the ID isnt defined in the file that im reading from, any way to make a for loop to set the IDs manualy?

I guess Arrays will be needed, but if someone can explain the syntax :)

Thx in Advance :)

Comment: Where are you calling your `toString()` method is your `TXTtoJSON` class?

Comment: To clarify: You have a .csv file and want to read its content, mapping each line to a transaction object. Also, you are not sure how to set the id property, as it is not provided. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes Glains! Separator is ";" and the file goes with the toString method to a json file!